# Creating an Agenda View for IBM iLog Calendar application

Tags: apache-flex, calendar, ilog-elixir

I am using the IBM iLog Elixir calendar for my website. Its working fine.

My issue is that, I want to create an agenda view for the events in the calendar for the date that is selected in the DataChooser (which I do by sending a request back to my database, and fetching the events for that particular date).

But the issue here is with the events that are recurrence. They have rules, and based on the rules the iLog calendar shows them on the calendar. But for me, I just check for the events with that date.

There are two solutions:

1. Is that I understand the rules in the database, and make a query that checks those rules and send me back the events.
2. Solution is, the iLog calendar already fetches all the events, and displays them according to where they should be. So, I should try to find a way to fetch these events from the calendar itself.

The solution second is a better choice, as it makes the calendar faster (as I dont have to send another request to database) and it also is already doing what I need. All I need to figure out how to fetch these events.

How can I fetch the events from calendar itself.

Comment: When you use the term "event" you are referring to data items displayed in the Calendar, correct?  If so; I don't understand what a recursive event is in this case.

Comment: date items, yes you are correct. I am sorry I mean recurrence events. Events that repeat. Eg repeat event every month, or every week on Tuesday.

Comment: I've never looked at the iLog code (I avoid it b/c I have an inherent conflict of interests).  You make it sound like it is tied to a specific backend/database structure.  Is that true?  I would assume they have some form of encapsulated class to handle recurring events; which I bet you'd be able to make us of.